# Not able to connect to DB when site uploaded to Plesk Panel

Tags: php, mysql, plesk

So, I have a very simple php configuration file to connect to a MySQL Database, called `connect.php` inside a folder called `modules`, which is included in all the pages that require access to the Database.
I have a user (let's call him `db_user`) created with the database (let's call it `db1`) from within my plesk panel.
Now when I try to access a database, through a custom login page that simply checks `db1` to see is username and password are a match, I get the following error logs:

> [Wed Jun 11 23:21:59 2014] [warn] [client 1.2.3.4] mod_fcgid: stderr: PHP Warning:  mysql_connect(): Access denied for user 'db_user'@'localhost' (using password: YES) in /var/www/vhosts/~sitename~/httpdocs/modules/connect.php on line 2, referer: http:// ~sitename~/admin/login
>
> [Wed Jun 11 23:21:59 2014] [warn] [client 1.2.3.4] mod_fcgid: stderr: PHP Warning:  mysql_select_db(): Access denied for user ''@'localhost' (using password: NO) in /var/www/vhosts/~sitename~/httpdocs/modules/connect.php on line 3, referer: http:// ~sitename~/admin/login
>
> [,,,] (more messages essentially saying it has not connected and as a result are trying to connect with no username and password)

The `connect.php` file is:

```
<?php
mysql_connect('localhost', 'db_user', 'password');
    mysql_select_db("db1");
?>
```

Here are the `SHOW GRANTS FOR db_user@'%';`

```
##Grants for db_user@%##
`GRANT USAGE ON *.* TO 'db1'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD '*BEE6E9D5D5A3C2E1EC93EBCA0E4E527C0328BE01'`

GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON `db_user`.* TO 'db1'@'%'
```

Mind that everything is running smoothly on my MAMP configuration back at my workstation, so I doubt there is any code related issue.
So, I have run out of ideas on what I could try to solve this...
Any suggestion would be very appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently in the database section there is a column named `Database server` which gives the address of the database, which in my case simply was not `localhost`, `127.0.0.1` or anything like that!

I changed the address and off it worked!